# SFML no sound playing with soundbuffers stored in ResourceHolder

Tags: c++, sfml

i'm currently working on a small game with sfml.

For resource loading and holding i'm using the ResourceHolder described in the SFML Game
Development Book: [SFML ResourceHolder](https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/blob/master/02_Resources/Include/Book/ResourceHolder.hpp) Basically the resources are stored as unique_ptr in a map.

Inside a SoundManager class i'm loading different sounds to this ResourceHolder. This SoundManager has a playSound function when i want to play a sound.

```
void SoundManager::playSound(SoundType soundToPlay) {
    auto buffer = sounds.get(soundToPlay);
    auto sound = sf::Sound(buffer);
    sound.play();
}
```

but i don't hear any sounds. Do i have to store different sound objects for every sound in a map? I also tried to use a sf::Sound object as a class member, but this also didn't worked.

Using this ResourceHolder my textures are loaded correctly.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue with some [enter link description here](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=28288.0) in the sfml-dev forum.